# System of three equations in three variables?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

Fibonacci apparently found some solutions to this problem:

Find rational solutions of:

$$x+y+z+x^2=u^2$$

$$x+y+z+x^2+y^2=v^2$$

$$x+y+z+x^2+y^2+z^2=w^2$$

How would you find solutions to this using the mathematics available in Fibonaccis's time? (of course by this I mostly mean without using calculus, series, and modern maths. Also please exclude modular arithmetic notation if possible.) I was able to find little bits of information by adding and subtracting equations, such as $z^2=w^2-v^2$, $y^2=v^2-u^2$, and $y^2+z^2=w^2-u^2$, but I really do not know what to do. Thanks.

Comment: Is your goal to find all solutions or some solutions ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy I don't know if there are a finite number of solutions, but if there were an infinite number, a proof of that would be nice.

Comment: A preliminary analysis: you are searching for rational solutions $(x,y,z)$ s.t. $y^2+z^2=w^2-u^2$. If $w^2-u^2<0$ there are none; if $w^2-u^2=0$ one has the solutions $(x,0,0)$ with rational $x$ s.t. $x+x^2=u^2=w^2$. Existence of rational solutions of the 2nd degree polynomial in $x$ depends on $w$. One has 2 rational solutions if $w=\frac{q^2-1}{4}$ for some real $q$, otherwise there are none. It remains to study the case $w^2-u^2>0$

Comment: @Avitus From OP's last derived equation (essentially a Pythagorean quadruple), then $w^2-u^2$ _will_ be greater than $0$, unless $y$ and $z$ are trivially $0$.

Comment: @alex.jordan I am not sure about this because I know nothing about $w$ and $u$, which I presume just to be fixed. If $y=z=0$, then there exists still space for non trivial rational solutions $(x,0,0)$.

Comment: Would it help if I included some of the solutions that Fibonacci found?

Comment: @Avitus, that's fair; 'trivial' is the wrong word. Rational solutions to $x+x^2=u^2$ can be found in the same way that Pythagorean triples are found. Project a line from $(x,u)=(-1,0)$ to a rational point on the curve $x+x^2=u^2$, and the line intersects the $u$ axis at a rational number. This is nearly a bijection between rationals on the $u$-axis and rational points on $x+x^2=u^2$.

Comment: Wolframalpha finds [these solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve[x+%2B+y+%2B+z+%2B+x^2+%3D%3D+u^2+%26%26+x+%2B+y+%2B+z+%2B+x^2+%2B+y^2+%3D%3D+v^2+%26%26++++x+%2B+y+%2B+z+%2B+x^2+%2B+y^2+%2B+z^2+%3D%3D+w^2%2C+{x%2C+y%2C+z}]). I think it is hard to find **rational** solutions if $u$, $v$, $w$ are not given.

Comment: @alex.jordan I thought $u$, $v$ and $w$ were fixed: so $y^2+z^2=w^2-u^2$ is a circle if $w^2-u^2>0$ and $x+x^2=w^2$ has 0 or 2 rational solutions.  I am a bit confused now: is this the setting that the OP was thinking about?

Comment: None of these are given, but some solutions are x=16/5, y=48/5, z=144/5, and x=35, y=144, z=360.

Comment: @Avitus I believe it's a system of three equations in six unknowns, and that OP is looking for sextuplets of rationals that satisfy the system. Is that right Ovi?

Comment: @Ovi your triples are not solutions unless you specify also $u$, $w$, $v$. Otherwise the triples you write just determine the values for $u$, $w$ and $v$. This is the point: are $u$, $v$ and $w$ parameters and $(x,y,z)$ the only variables?

Comment: @Ovi: The question needs revision, you are looking for rational solutions of $(x,y,z,u,v,w)$ or just $(x,y,z)$ and $(u,v,w)$ being integers?

Comment: There are lots of examples in Dickson's history of the theory of numbers in which, in previous centuries, it was popular to take a number of left-hand sides (expressions in some variables), and ask for ways to make them all squares. The OP's question seems exactly of this type, especially as $u^2,v^2,w^2$ appear only on the right sides of the three equations. So I think the interpretation is that one should take the three expressions in rational $x,y,z$ and try to make them all rational squares. (it's not a homogeneous system so can't go to integers immediately.)

Comment: FYI: You can manipulate the first equation twice: isolate the $y$ term and square, then isolate the new $z$ term (more exactly, the $2z(u^2-x-x^2)$ term) and square. The result is a polynomial with even powers of $y$ and $z$, which you can write in terms of $u$, $v$, $w$ by your previous work. This is a monic degree-8 polynomial in $x$. I don't know that this really helps much with @coffeemath's (and alex.jordan's, and my) interpretation of the problem, but it's another "little bit of information".

Comment: @Inceptio I am looking for rational solutions to $(x, y, z, u, v, w)$. I know that in the solutions I posted I only provided $(x, y, z)$, but that's what was give, I didn't actually take the time to calculate $(u, v, w)$

Comment: @Avitus Well the whole point is that when you do plug in those specific $(x, y, z)$ and solve for $(u, v, w)$, $(u, v, w)$ turn out to be rational.

Comment: @Ovi I think the whole point is to search for various choices of $x,y,z$ for which the three left sides come out to be rational squares, and then one simply *denotes* those squares by the expressions $u^2,v^2,w^2$. Fibonacci found some cases, and the challenge is to find more, not knowing what $u,v,w$ are to be in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a full answer in that not all solutions are described. But the discussion yields two infinite parametrized families of solutions. And the methods could possibly be studied longer to find more families, and possibly parametrize all solutions. As proof that this works before you invest in studying it, check that the solution it predicts at the end is valid.

There is a known trick for parametrizing rational points on quadratic surfaces, that I think extends to hypersurfaces.

Take the first equation. $(x,y,z,u)=(0,0,0,0)$ is a rational solution. Suppose $(X,Y,Z,U)$ is a different rational solution. Then the line connecting these two points in $4$-space is parametrized by $(x,y,z,u)=t(X,Y,Z,U)$. This line intersects the surface $x+y+z+x^2=u^2$ in precisely two places, since the intersection is found by solving for $t$ in $tX+tY+t^2Z^2=t^2U^2$. One solution is clearly given by $t=0$, and the other is given by $t=\frac{X+Y}{U^2-Z^2}$. Now since the line is parametrized by rational numbers, the intersection of this line with the plane $u=1$ has all rational coordinates: $(a,b,c,1)$. We can solve for $t$ to bring the fourth coordinate to $1$, and have $t=1/U$. So $$\begin{align}a&=X/U\\b&=Y/U\\c&=Z/U\end{align}$$

This establishes a map from rational points on $x+y+z+x^2=u^2$ to rational points on $u=1$. But this map is reversible. Take any rational triple $(a,b,c,1)$ and consider the line connecting this point to $(0,0,0,0)$. This line is parametrized by $(x,y,z,u)=s(a,b,c,1)$, and intersects $x+y+z+x^2=u^2$ in two places. To find both, we substitute: $as+bs+cs+a^2s^2=s^2$, and along with $s=0$, the other solution is with $s=\frac{a+b+c}{1-a^2}$.

So rational solutions to your first equation are given by $$\begin{align}x&=a\frac{a+b+c}{1-a^2}\\y&=b\frac{a+b+c}{1-a^2}\\z&=c\frac{a+b+c}{1-a^2}\\u&=\frac{a+b+c}{1-a^2}\end{align}$$ where $a,b,c$ are any triple of rationals excluding $a=\pm1$.

One infinite family of solutions to the system arises out of this if we take $b=c=0$: $(x,y,z,u,v,w)=\left(\frac{a^2}{1-a^2},0,0,\frac{a}{1-a^2},\pm\frac{a}{1-a^2},\pm\frac{a}{1-a^2}\right)$.

---

We can see what happens if we throw these into the next equation.

$$\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{1-a^2}+(a^2+b^2)\left(\frac{a+b+c}{1-a^2}\right)^2=v^2$$

Unfortunately this equation is degree 6:

$$(1+b^2)(a+b+c)^2=v^2(1-a^2)^2$$

So trying to proceed as before but this time in $(a,b,c,v)$-space won't work. Lines will not be guaranteed to intersect the surface at two points, which is a crucial element of what we did above.

If we are merely hunting families of solutions, and give up (for now) on finding all solutions, then it would help to have $1+b^2$ be a square. That is, to have $1+b^2=d^2$. We can do this by finding any primitive Pythagorean triple $(m^2-n^2)^2+(2mn)^2=(m^2+n^2)^2$ and dividing by  one of the left terms. Say we choose the second term, so that for *integers* $m$ and $n$, we have $$\begin{align}b&=\frac{m^2-n^2}{2mn}\\d&=\frac{m^2+n^2}{2mn}\end{align}$$ Now the earlier equation reduces to $$d(a+b+c)=v(1-a^2)$$

If we take $c=0$ (implying $z=0$) then we have another family of solutions to the system that arises out of this. Taking $m,n$ to be free nonzero integers, $a$ a free rational not equal to $1$, we have $$(x,y,z,u,v,w)=\left(a\frac{a+\frac{m^2-n^2}{2mn}}{1-a^2},\frac{m^2-n^2}{2mn}\frac{a+\frac{m^2-n^2}{2mn}}{1-a^2},0,\frac{a+\frac{m^2-n^2}{2mn}}{1-a^2},\frac{m^2+n^2}{2mn}\frac{a+\frac{m^2-n^2}{2mn}}{1-a^2},\pm\frac{m^2+n^2}{2mn}\frac{a+\frac{m^2-n^2}{2mn}}{1-a^2}\right)$$

For example, $m=1$, $n=2$, $a=3/5$ yields $(-9/64, 45/256,0,-15/64, -75/256,75/256)$.

---

It seems reasonable that some other family could be worked out this way that does not demand $z=0$.